# Duvida do better align no Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Estou tentando configurar o Better Align no Vscode, já segui alguns tutoriais e ate algumas respostas aqui do Stack, porem sem conseguir chegar no resultado esperado. Gostaria de deixar o espaçamento igual (tanto nos "=", quanto nos "=>") Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço[image: ![sem usar o comando para identar]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gLhX.png)[[image: após inserir o comando para identar]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Otc.png)

Comment: desculpa mas, por qual motivo fazer isso? outra sua pergunta não é de programação !!!

Comment: eu q peço desculpas, pela minha falta de experiencia....Mas vamos lá, por qual motivo fazer? para que os códigos que eu venha a digitar fiquem "alinhados" para que eu , com minha pouca experiencia os possa entender; e minha pergunta não é sobre programação? realmente não compreendi sua visão, afinal o VsCode não é um editor de códigos? e oq eu irei digitar neles não são uma sequencia de "comandos" para que executem algo em um site ou sistema? e isso não se refere a programação??? Realmente, desculpe a ignorancia deste mero aprendiz diante de um programador experiente...

Comment: a sua pergunta não é exatamente uma duvida de um código, ou de um conceito mediante algum exemplo, mas, de formatação de um editor. Talvez essa formatação a longo do tempo você vai mudar, porque não é assim que deve ser feito, bom são minhas experiencias